# How to check state of a checkbox and update database accordingly

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I am making a check to see if the user account is freeze, this is in my database, $r is where I am getting the user data (name, freeze account, etc).

So if the freeze account is set to be 0 then I am showing a unchecked box otherwise a checked box. It works fine, however my question is how could I save it if I checked the box to say that the user account is freeze.

I know how to write the query if they check the box to say that the user account is freeze, just calling this function :

```
function updatefreezeaccount(){
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `freeze_account` = 1 WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'");
}
```

This is my code so far :

```
<?php
      if ($r['freeze_account'] == 0) {
          echo '<div class="example">
          <input type="checkbox" unchecked data-toggle="toggle">
          </div>';
      } 
      else {
          echo '<div class="example">
          <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
          </div>';
      }
?>
```

I don't have a form, so I want to know if I can do it without having a form
However I don't know how to make the check to see if the user has checked the box or not, any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: when you want to check the checkbox?? After submitting any form or just usual??

Comment: I don't want to have a form, so is that possible ? like soon as you check the box it updates it by calling the function ?

Comment: how the function call without submitting? Is it a PHP or ajax or jQuery?

Comment: I am just asking if there is anyway of going without having a form, and will be using PHP

Comment: Would it be possible thorugh jquery to see if it's been selected and then if it is using php to call that function ?

Comment: yes, wait for my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104455/discussion-between-jomin-george94-and-frayne-konok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST` can also be used to get some data from the server. However, the POST method NEVER caches data, and is often used to send data along with the request.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
            //here you need to call the page where your update query has
            var user_id = "<?php echo $user_id;?>"; //if $user id present in the same page
            $.post("your_page.php", {user_id : user_id}, function(feedback){
                  alert(feedback);// the feedback is come form the `your_page.php`, what you want to return
            });
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
            alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
        }
    });
});
```

You can also pass your user_id as an attribute of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You will need javascript to do this. If you are using jquery, then you can do simply `$(selector).on('click', function(){ Call to server side });` or you can go vanilla js and do something like `<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>` and write a js function do the server side call.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use JavaScript and a framework, like jQuery.  This is a front end issue, not a backend issue.

So something like this would work.

```
$('#the-checkbox').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $.post('to-your-form', {client_id: 'client_id', 'freeze':'1'}, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    } else {
        $.post('to-your-form', {client_id: 'client_id', 'freeze':'0'}, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
});
```